# When a GIF is loaded to the page, all other Gifs with the SAME URL start playing from beginning

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, gif

I'd like to make GIF's only starting to play once they are actually on the screen. I came up with a small JS Script that basically replaces a static image (the first frame of the gif) with the actual gif, as soon as the image is on the monitor.

I can't really change that much in the HTML section since i'm working in a CMS.

HTML:

```
<div class="lazy">
    <img src="firstframe.png">
    <img src="gif.gif">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var lazies = $('.lazy');
lazies.each(function(){
    var src = $(this).find('img').eq(1).attr('src');
    if($(this)[0].offsetTop <= window.innerHeight && !$(this).hasClass('lazyactive')){
        $(this).find('img').eq(0).attr('src', src);
        $(this).find('img').eq(1).hide();
        $(this).addClass('lazyactive');
    }
})

window.onscroll = function(){
    lazies.each(function(i){
        if(window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight >= $(this)[0].offsetTop && !$(this).hasClass('lazyactive')){
            var src = $(this).find('img').eq(1).attr('src')
            $(this).addClass('lazyactive');
            $(this).find('img').eq(0).attr('src', src);
            $(this).find('img').eq(1).hide();
        }
    })
}
```

The code works fine as long as i have different GIF's on the page.
But as soon as i have the same GIF multiple times on the page, i have a problem. Every time one of the PNG get's replaced with the GIF (by scrolling down), every GIF starts to play from beginning.

I'm not sure if that's normal behaviour of the browsers or the error is in my script..

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to the browser caching the images; one way to fix that is to make the URL unique by adding a random parameter: `/somegif.gif?a`, then `/somegif.gif?b` for the next, and so on.

Comment: I don't see the point in your lazy loader - as you have both images in the dom, both will get loaded so you are actually slowing down your page by adding an extra image.  Also most lazy loaders use the same image (not the first frame) so that only one image gets loaded when of screen (as you can't see it) meaning there will be less requests

Comment: Yeah, but that's an easy fix. Just use `data-src` to store the `src` for the gifs (and a single image)

Comment: I can't (don't want to) use data-src, because im working in a CMS. I'd like other users to just "rebuild" the html using existing CMS components (where i can't add custom tags) and then include my JS script on the page. :)

Comment: @Pete you are right it isn't a lazy loader, i'm using this because the GIF's should only play once without looping. So if i just add the GIF's on the bottom of the page, by the time the user get's there the GIF's have finished playing allready